# Get unlimited char in Cpp

Tags: c++, string, char

I want to get unlimited chars, actually I created char*, I use cin for it, and I want to change it to string.
I don't know the length of the input which user enters, so I made this solution for myself.
Can someone tell me plz, how to get a char* without knowing the size of input and converting to string.
thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just use `std::string`?

Comment: You could create a linked list. But that's way less efficient over time than what std::string does, which is hold some buffer that begins at an initial size, and then reallocates a larger buffer when it gets too big.

Comment: Actually I Want another solution , not getting string, I wanna solve my problem in getting unlimited char,is there anyway except linkedlist?

Comment: @Zahra Alternatively you could use a `std::unique_ptr<char[]> s(new char[arbitrary_length]);`. But you would need to manage the NUL termination yourself, and still know a maximum length before taking input. The better way is to simply use `std::string`.

Comment: If you don't want to use `std::string` then you have to implement the functionality of `std::getline` yourself. Maybe you could copy the source to your project and tinker with it.

Answer (score 5):

Since it is C++. Just use `std::string`

If you really need to use `char*` look at [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30271631/dynamically-allocate-user-inputted-string)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a `char *`, use the standard library.

```
  #include <string>
  #include <iostream>

  int main()
  {
       std::string data;

       std::getline(std::cin, data);

       std::cout << data << '\n';
  }
```

This will read a string of any length (at least, until a newline is entered, which will not be included in `data`) and then print it out.

You might wish to also check the state of `std::cin` to test if any errors occurred.

Comment: Thank you a lot @Peter , but actually I'm searching for the way which I can get char.
thank you for your reply!

Comment: @Zahra - Read the documentation for `std::string`.   It has member functions that provide access to the underlying data ..... as a pointer to (the first element of) a dynamically allocated array of `char` i.e. a `const char *`.   If you try to work with a raw pointer (instead of `std::string`), you'll need to manually manage the memory allocation and (just as importantly) deallocation when you no longer need it.